# Dev-C++ cannot find <iostream> or <iostream.h> header files

Tags: c++

Dev-C++ cannot find the I/O stream header files. I tried it with both `#include <iostream>` and `#include <iostream.h>` but I get the following errors.

```
[Error] iostream.h: No such file or directory
[Error] iostream: No such file or directory
```

What can I check in the Dev-C++ settings to make sure it's properly configured to build programs that use the C++ Standard Library?

Comment: Use `#include <iostream>`, and better yet don't use Dev C++, switch to a better compiler

Comment: pleas tell me whisch compiler is best?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @CoryKramer: There is nothing wrong with Dev-C++, which is not a compiler.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit correct it is an IDE and has GCC under the hood, but it notorious for being behind the curve, and there are stronger free alternatives IMHO

Comment: @CoryKramer: That was like a decade ago. It was long ago forked and is fine. "There are stronger free alternatives" is a long way off dictating "don't use"!

Comment: who keeps accepting crap edits?

Comment: Use: roswell dev c++ it is basically the same thing but is updated more recently than the original and wx version.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
```

You've got a double 's' in your code as far as I can see and that may be causing a problem. If including "iostream" header file won't work as well it means that your Dev-C++ (sic!) is probably not linked with MinGW properly.

As the others said, consider using f.e. Code::Blocks instead Dev-C++.

Comment: The double s was added by an edit, it wasn't in the original question.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice. Thanks for paying attenton, sir.

Answer (score -2):

If you didn't download the Dev C++ that includes MinGW then you don't have the standard libraries. If you do have the standard libraries you will need to make sure to set it up by [pointing it to the location of the source on your system](http://www.bloodshed.net/faq.html#5).

If you still need the standard libraries, you can go to "Downloads" section of [this page](http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/devcpp.html) and go to the first link which includes MinGW.

But your best bet is to send Dev C++ off to die in a fire. The incredibly powerful Visual Studio 2015 is out and the Community version is free: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs There's really no excuse for using anything else on Windows.

Comment: _"Dev C++ does not include the standard library source"_ What nonsense is this?! Of course it does. It ships with MinGW, which ships with all the standard headers. And please stop spreading all this FUD about "sending it off to die in a fire". There are _plenty_ of "excuses" not to use Visual Studio 2015, mainly that it is extremely, extremely buggy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :) I've tried to clarify, but even in the original answer I wrote you can see that there is an "Executable Only" which does *not* include MinGW.

Comment: Then the compilation process could not happen at all; it would not get as far as attempting to locate header files in an `#include` directive.